# Grid of values into density plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to convert a grid of values into a density plot to make a picture that shows the structure of the silicon surface that was scanned. The file of values is called stm.txt and can be found here: 
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cp/programs.html

I really can't figure this one out so I'm in some real need of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's `loadtxt` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to load your data, and then `imshow` (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grid = np.loadtxt("stm.txt")
plt.imshow(grid)
plt.show()
```

[image: Density plot of stm.txt]

Comment: @BrandonSeedlessBananasMc-Wil: If this answers the question, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that? I'm new to this site.